# Algorithm design for semi sorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search

If you are given an array or ints, and for every i, 1 <= i <= n - k, a[i] < a[i+k], how can you use this information to sort faster than normal? For instance the array {2, 5, 7, 4, 8, 9} and k = 3, 2 < 4 and 5 < 8 and 7 < 9. The array and the k value are provided to the function.

Comment: You're basically merging k sorted arrays: [a[0], a[k], a[2*k]...], [a[1], a[k+1], a[2*k+1]...], ...

Comment: @m69 Can you explain this any more? I don't see how its k sorted from your comment.

Comment: Every element a[i] is smaller than element a[i+k]; that means that a[i], a[i+k], a[i+2*k], a[i+3*k], ... form a sorted array. So there's a sorted array starting at a[0], one at a[1], one at a[2], ... one at a[k-1], each made up of elements that are k positions apart.

Comment: Ah that makes sense now, thanks for the help.